# How to make scanner input to be on the same line as question?

Tags: java, cursor

I want the input of the scanner to be on the same line as the question.
By code is as below

```
String choice;
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter your choice: ");
choice = scanner.next().toUpperCase();
```

Current console output:

```
Enter your choice:         

A
```

Desired console output:

```
Enter your choice: A
```

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Use `System.out.print("Enter your choice: ")` .

Answer (score 2):

You can print without a new line using

```
System.out.print("Enter your choice: ");
```